# Print Out Dataframe Rows Between Two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with random repeating sequences. I need to set a flag of sorts so that every time I come across the term maintenance, I store the rows between each instance. " store everything between the two maintenance instances." The input is:

```
name 0   process 0 
name 1   maintenance 
name 2   process 2
name 3   process 3
name 4   process 4
name 5   process 5
name 6   maintenance 
name 7   process 7
name 8   process 8
name 9   process 9 
name 10  maintenance 
name 11  process 11
name 12  process 12
name 13  process 13
name 14  process 14
name 15  maintenance
```

I was thinking about doing a set of logical conditions:

```
for i in np.arange(len(df)-1):
  if df['process'][i] = 'maintenance':
     df['new'] = df[i]
```

but, I am hoping there is a way that pandas can handle this (that I cant find) as I cant seem to figure out the stopping condition.

desired output:

```
name 2   process 2
name 3   process 3
name 4   process 4
name 5   process 5
name 11  process 11
name 12  process 12
name 13  process 13
name 14  process 14
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal input (no ...) and the matching expected output.

Comment: Is there a limit on how many times `maintenance` can arise in the frame? Is it 2, or more?

Comment: There is no limit to how many times maintenance can appear, but it will always appear as a pair. I do not want to store the rows that contain maintenance, just whats inbetween the two instances.

Comment: @mozway I updated the post to show my desired out put given a basic input

Comment: @MitchellMatheny can you provide an example with more than 2 maintenance? And ideally with rows after the last maintenance (and before the first) to see how to handle those cases

Comment: @mozway I added the entries as you asked. I need be able to pull out the desired data every time a sequence like the one shown occurs. This could be 2 times or 100 in the same data set

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['process']=='maintenance', df['name'], np.nan)
df
###
    name      process    new
0  name1  maintenance  name1
1  name2     process2    NaN
2  name3     process3    NaN
3  name4     process4    NaN
4  name5  maintenance  name5
```

```
df['new2'] = df[['name','process']].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)
df
###
    name      process    new               new2
0  name1  maintenance  name1  name1 maintenance
1  name2     process2    NaN     name2 process2
2  name3     process3    NaN     name3 process3
3  name4     process4    NaN     name4 process4
4  name5  maintenance  name5  name5 maintenance
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention a repeating sequence, I assume `maintenance` can arise many times but always as a multiple of two, indicating a start and end of a sequence of processes each maintenance window encapsulates.

In turn, this could be the solution:

```py
df_new = df[((df['process']=='maintenance').astype(int).cumsum()%2==1) | (df['process']=='maintenance')]
```

Note that it includes the rows with `maintenance` too.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating over the rows, set a flag to start adding the rows when the term maintenance is found and stop when maintenance is seen again, and so on.

The following should collect the rows you're looking for.

```python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """name,process
name 0,process 0
name 1,maintenance
name 2,process 2
name 3,process 3
name 4,process 4
name 5,process 5
name 6,maintenance
name 7,process 7
name 8,process 8
name 9,process 9
name 10,maintenance
name 11,process 11
name 12,process 12
name 13,process 13
name 14,process 14
name 15,maintenance"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
collect = False
row_list = []
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    if row.process == "maintenance":
        # toggle collect flag on/off
        collect = not collect
    elif collect:
        print(row.name, row.process, sep="\t")
        # do following if want to add row to a new dataframe
        row_list.append(row)

# create a new data frame with only the selected rows
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(row_list, columns=df.columns)
```

**Output:**

```
name 2  process 2
name 3  process 3
name 4  process 4
name 5  process 5
name 11 process 11
name 12 process 12
name 13 process 13
name 14 process 14
```